# How do I find and fix an uncaught exception?

Tags: android, uncaught-exception

I don't know how to figure out where an uncaught exception is coming from.  I have looked through the stackoverflow posts and tried looking for several of the solutions.  As far as I can tell, I have my activity, "Monitor", listed in my manifest and it is part of the package.  But I get a null pointer exception when I start the "Monitor" activity.  What should I be looking for to find this exception?

```
02-03 21:44:14.192: E/Trace(19701): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
02-03 21:44:14.262: I/BugSenseHandler(19701): Registering default exceptions handler
02-03 21:44:14.633: I/Setup(19701): Setup activity created
02-03 21:44:14.813: I/BugSenseHandler(19701): Flushing...
02-03 21:44:14.823: I/BugSenseHandler(19701): Registering default exceptions handler
02-03 21:44:15.023: W/BugSenseHandler(19701): Transmitting ping Exception No peer certificate
02-03 21:44:15.403: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(19701): <ConfigWindowMatch:2087>: Format RGBA_8888.
02-03 21:44:15.594: E/(19701): <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading
02-03 21:44:15.594: E/(19701): <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading
02-03 21:44:19.318: W/dalvikvm(19701): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41bfb438)
02-03 21:44:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19701): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-03 21:44:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19701): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.mpeterson.sousvide/com.mpeterson.sousvide.Monitor}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-03 21:44:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19701):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2024)
02-03 21:44:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19701):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2132)
02-03 21:44:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19701):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
02-03 21:44:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19701):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1231)
02-03 21:44:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19701):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-03 21:44:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19701):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-03 21:44:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19701):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
02-03 21:44:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19701):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-03 21:44:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19701):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-03 21:44:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19701):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
02-03 21:44:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19701):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
02-03 21:44:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19701):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-03 21:44:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19701): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-03 21:44:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19701):    at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1851)
02-03 21:44:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19701):    at com.mpeterson.sousvide.Monitor.<init>(Monitor.java:51)
02-03 21:44:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19701):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
02-03 21:44:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19701):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
02-03 21:44:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19701):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
02-03 21:44:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19701):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2015)
02-03 21:44:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19701):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: you get `NPE` on `findViewById`, make sure you use correct id

Comment: what is line number 51 in Monitor activity?

Comment: private final TextView tvCurTemp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextCurTemp);
This is my first findViewById.  It refers to an existing editText field.  In Eclipse, this field name shows up as blue so I think that means it's registered somewhere.

Comment: check if its in the same xml as the one in setContentView

Comment: I'm not sure where setContentView is.  That is not one of my activities.

Comment: Please post your Monitor activity code, and your layout file where you've defined editTextCurTemp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provided that you have editTextCurTemp defined as TextView in your_layout_file.xml, you must call

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_file)
```

**BEFORE** you do any findViewById(), otherwise you will get NPE.

Comment: That was it.  Very frustrating because I have been using the app with the findViewById in my global variables area without any errors for weeks.  Not sure why it just started to be finicky.  Thanks for the help.